# Download a file on the basis of language (Current Culture)

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

I am working on a windows application which downloads a template from http URL using WebClient.

I have to implement localization in report. Application will always be in default language(English) and i will have a variable which will hold the language in which report has to be printed. Report template will be downloaded on the basis of language. Report templates are different for each language having naming convention like

default: http://www.xyz.com/report/report.htm

English: report.en-US.htm, 
Spanish: report.es-ES.htm
Portuguese: report.pt-PT.htm

Do i have ti use switch..case for each language or it is possible any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filename format will stay same you could do this

```
string cultureCode = "en-US"; //set current locale    
Uri reportUri = new Uri(String.Format("http://www.xyz.com/report/report.{0}.htm", cultureCode), UriKind.Absolute);
```

That way it'll dynamically create the URI for you with the relevant locale added. As a quick method

```
public void Uri GetLocalReportUri(string cultureCode)
{  
   return new Uri(String.Format("http://www.xyz.com/report/report.{0}.htm", cultureCode), UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the current culture name from

[`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

or

[`System.Web.HttpRequest.UserLanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx)

so then you can do something along the lines of

`string url = string.Format("http://www.xyz.com/report/report{0}.htm", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);`

which outputs like

`http://www.xyz.com/report/report.en-US.htm`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Globalization class to get your current culture. Try the following.

```
string culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;

string destUri = String.Format("http://www.xyz.com/report/report.{0}.htm", culture);
```